# how do i keep adding data to an array to be displayed in a listview in xamarin for android

Tags: c#, android, arrays, android-arrayadapter, xamarin.android

so far i have this:

```
btnAddContact.Click += delegate {
            String[] nameList = new string[]{nameText.Text, ipText.Text};

            var myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.TextViewItem, nameList);
            contactView.Adapter = myAdapter;
            myAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            nameText.Text = "";
            };
```

Two EditText fields, a button and a ListView - when i add data into the two text fields and click the button it adds the data to an array and then displays it in the ListView.. except if i try to add another value to the array via the text fields, it just changes what was already entered..

how do i do this so it keeps adding the data forming a list?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out on my own.. This is something other people told me could only be achieved through a custom adapter so it may be useful to someone else.

Created a public array

```
public ArrayList nameList = new ArrayList ();
```

then on a button click, assigned the add to array code.

```
btnAddContact.Click += delegate {
            nameList.Add(nameText.Text + " " + ipText.Text);
            var myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.TextViewItem, nameList);
            contactView.Adapter = myAdapter;
            myAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            nameText.Text = "";
            ipText.Text = "";
            };
```

This puts the name and ip address on the same line with a space in between so it's easily readable.

Comment: Pull out line 3 and 4 out of your Click handler and put them in `OnCreate`. No reason to override the `Adapter` all the time.

Comment: In fact it won't work if not overriding the adapter. Instead it will crash, because ArrayAdapter has probably a bug.